# How to remove automatic picture rotation?

Tags: android

I have a problem with pictures; after I take a picture, it automatically rotates 90-degrees. How I can remove this? I need a portrait picture.

```
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
{



 try
 {

     camera.setPreviewCallback(this);
         camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
         Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
         p.setPictureSize(1024, 768);
         p.setPictureFormat (PixelFormat.RGB_565);
         camera.setParameters(p);


      }


 catch (IOException e)
 {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }





 if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_CAR)
 {

     camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

 }
 else
 {

     camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);

 }

 preview.setLayoutParams(lp);
 camera.startPreview();
}

  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, Camera paramCamera)
  {


 FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

 try {

 File saveDir = new File("/sdcard/CameraExample/");

 if (!saveDir.exists())
 {
 saveDir.mkdirs();
 }

 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();



 Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(paramArrayOfByte, 0,paramArrayOfByte.length, options);

 Bitmap bmpResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImage.getWidth(), myImage.getHeight(),Config.RGB_565);




 Paint paint = new Paint();         

 Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(bmpResult);

 myCanvas.drawBitmap(myImage, 0, 0, paint);




  fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/CameraExample/"+ sdf.format(new        Date())+".bmp");

 BufferedOutputStream bos = newBufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream );


 bmpResult.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);

 bos.flush();
 bos.close();
```

Comment: Show code where you creating that image.

Comment: Edited, but in my opinion is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_CAR)
{

     Matrix mat = new Matrix();
     mat.preRotate(90);
     Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpResult, 0, 0,
                    myImage.getWidth(), myImage.getHeight(), mat, true);

}
```

Comment: yes everything is fine, but it cuts the picture (right and below.